# Apex Controller not Displaying VF Page

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller, class

I think my controller class isnt executing as it should. I am trying to say if Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c is blank and et4ae5__ExactTargetForAppExchangeUser__c is ticked, then show me visual force page.

Field : Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c
DataType : Date

Field : et4ae5__ExactTargetForAppExchangeUser__c 
DataType : Checkbox

Here is my controller class

```
   /********************************************************************
   * DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController
   *
   * Controller class for MarketingCloudPolicyPage
   * 
   * Author: Daniel Mason
   * Created: 14/09/2015
   * add et4ae5__ExactTargetForAppExchangeUser__c = True logic userloggedin
   * 
   ********************************************************************/

public class DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController{

Id uid; 
User loggedInUser;

public DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController(){
    uid = UserInfo.getUserId();
    loggedInUser = [SELECT Id, Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c 
          FROM User
          WHERE Id = :uid
          LIMIT 1];
} 

public PageReference closePopupAccept() { 
    // Method to write back data policy acceptance date to user on accept
    loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c = date.today();
    update loggedInUser;        
    PageReference p = new PageReference('/home/home.jsp');
    p.setRedirect(true);      
    return p;
  } 

  public PageReference closePopupDecline() { 
    // Method to logout user afer decline 
    PageReference p = new PageReference('/secur/logout.jsp');
    p.setRedirect(true);      
    return p; 
   }

   public static Data_Policy__c getPolicy(){
    // Method to obtain data policy text
    Data_Policy__c dp = [SELECT Id, Name, Start_Date__c, MarketingCloudPolicyText__c 
                         FROM Data_Policy__c
                         LIMIT 1];

    return dp;
  }

  public boolean getRedirect(){
    // Method to determine show popup
    boolean redirect = false;     
    Data_Policy__c dp = getPolicy(); 
    Data_Policy_Settings__c dps = Data_Policy_Settings__c.getInstance(UserInfo.getProfileId());            
    if(dps.Show_Marketing_Policy__c == true && (loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c == null && loggedInUser.et4ae5__ExactTargetForAppExchangeUser__c == True || loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c.addYears(1) < date.today() || loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c < dp.Start_Date__c)){                              
        redirect = true;
    } 
    return redirect;
   }}
```

here is my Controller test

```
/********************************************************************
*DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController_Test
*
*Test class for DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController
*
*Author: Daniel Mason 
*Created: 14/09/2015
*The @isTest class annotation indicates this class only contains test methods.
*Classes defined with the @isTest annotation do not count against the organization 
*size limit for all Apex scripts.See the Apex Language Reference for more information
*about Testing and Code Coverage. Look @ BG coding standards if any doubts 
** Using Profile System admin X japan as  FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION on System Admin profile
********************************************************************/

@isTest 
private class  DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController_Test{
static testMethod void DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController_Test(){

/*
*  Test Accept & Decline of Marketing Cloude policy
*/

    Profile prof1 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile  WHERE Name = 'System Administrator - Ex Japan'];


    User user1 = new User();
    user1.FirstName = 'Daniel';
    user1.LastName = 'Mason';
    user1.Email = 'daniel.mason@schroders.com';
    user1.Username = 'daniel.mason@schroders.com';
    user1.Alias = 'DMaso';
    user1.CommunityNickname = 'DMaso';
    user1.TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles';
    user1.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
    user1.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
    user1.ProfileId = prof1.Id;
    user1.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
    user1.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c = null;
    insert user1;

   //Setup Custom Setting for profile
    Data_Policy_Settings__c dps = new Data_Policy_Settings__c();
    dps.Show_Marketing_Policy__c = true;
    dps.SetupOwnerId = prof1.Id;

    //Create Test Policy
    Data_Policy__c dp1 = new Data_Policy__c();
    dp1.Name = 'Test Data Policy';
    dp1.Start_Date__c = date.today();
    dp1.MarketingCloudPolicyText__c = 'Everyone Loves creating test classes ...';
    insert dp1;

    system.assertEquals(1, [SELECT Count() FROM User WHERE email = 'daniel.mason@schroders.com' LIMIT 1]);

    PageReference pageRef = Page.DataPolicyPage;


    System.runAs(user1){
    test.startTest();
    DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController controllerInstance = new DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController();
    boolean redirect = controllerInstance.getRedirect();

    test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController controller = new DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController();

    //Declining VF Page  
    PageReference logout = controller.closePopupDecline();
    system.assertEquals('/secur/logout.jsp',logout.getURL());

    //Accepting VF Page
    controller.closePopupAccept();
    user1 = [SELECT Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c FROM User WHERE email = 'daniel.mason@schroders.com'LIMIT 1];

    system.assertEquals(date.today(),user1.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c);
    Data_Policy__c dataPolicy = DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController.getPolicy();
    system.assertEquals(true,dataPolicy != null);
    test.stopTest();
    }
    }
   }
```

This is the visual Force page it should be calling

```
    <apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" controller="DM_MarketingCloudPolicyController">
    <apex:outputPanel id="policy">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="custPopup" layout="block">
            <apex:pageBlock title="Marketing Cloud Data Policy">
                <apex:image url="{!$Resource.Boliva}"/>
                <br></br>
                Welcome {! $User.firstname & ' ' & $User.lastname}, please read the following data policy and accept the terms and conditions.
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
                <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;height:400px" >
                <apex:outputField value="{!policy.MarketingCloudPolicyText__c}"/>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                <br></br>
                <br></br>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:form >
                <center>   
                <apex:commandButton value="Accept" action="{!closePopupAccept}" rerender="policy"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Decline" action="{!closePopupDecline}" rerender="policy"/>
                </center>
            </apex:form>    
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:outputPanel>

 <style type="text/css">
    .custPopup{
        background-color: white;
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        z-index: 9999;
        left: 50%;
        padding:10px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 800px;
        margin-left: -400px;
        top:25px;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the line in your controller that must be satisfied for the redirect to be true:

```
if(dps.Show_Marketing_Policy__c == true 
   && (loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c == null 
      && loggedInUser.et4ae5__ExactTargetForAppExchangeUser__c == True 
      || loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c.addYears(1) 
      < date.today() 
      || loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c 
      < dp.Start_Date__c
      ))
{ 
redirect = true;
```

I see in your test class where you're satisfying

```
dps.Show_Marketing_Policy__c == true (under //Setup Custom Setting for profile)
```

I also see where your runAs user satisfies the 2nd requirement of

```
loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c == null (user1.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c = null;)
```

But, I don't see where either of the following 3 possible conditions have been satisfied:

```
      && loggedInUser.et4ae5__ExactTargetForAppExchangeUser__c == True 
      || loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c.addYears(1) 
      < date.today() 
      || loggedInUser.Marketing_Cloud_Acceptance_Date__c 
      < dp.Start_Date__c
```

Did you perhaps mean to use `||` where you have `&&` at the start of the above??